# Matrix and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $K$ is symmetric and positive-definite, and $v_k$ is eigenvector for $\lambda_k$ eigenvalue of $K$.
I can not understand why the following equation is correct:

$$\langle\vec v_k,K\vec v_k\rangle=\lambda_k||\vec v||^2$$
(standard matrix inner product).
I know that $K\vec v_k=λ\vec v_k$, but how do I "open" the inner product to prove the correctness of the equation?

Comment: What do you need to open? Inner product is by definition linear in one of its argumetns (in your case, it should be the right one, I guess). That is, $\langle x,\lambda y\rangle=\lambda\langle x,y\rangle$.

Comment: For example $⟨x,y⟩=x_1*y_1+⋯+x_n*y_n$
i want to see the components to understand why it is equal to $λk||v||^2$

Comment: Avoid coordinates whenever possible, they're a plague.  Use the linearity of the inner product instead as @Daniel suggested.  (And the equation is true for *any* inner product, not just the standard one.)

Comment: @Michael Hoppe (just to be sure) It don't matter that $A$ is matrix,we still get that $⟨x,Ay⟩=A⟨x,y⟩$?

Comment: @NFLX No! $\langle x,\,Ay\rangle$ is a scalar; $A\langle x,\,y\rangle$ is a matrix times a scalar.

Comment: @NFLX Not at all: it's rather senseless since the left hand side is a number while the right hand side is a matrix ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Daniel and @MichaelHoppe are right to encourage you to use$$K|v_k\rangle=\lambda_k|v_k\rangle\implies\langle v_k,\,Kv_k\rangle=\langle v_k,\,\lambda_kv_k\rangle=\lambda_k\langle v_k,\,v_k\rangle,$$provided we work with a linear-in-right-argument convention (which physicists favour; mathematicians don't). If you must see it done in coordinates (which is a pedagogically valuable exercise), let's choose an orthonormal basis viz. $\langle i,\,j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$. Then the identity operator is $\Bbb I=\sum_i|i\rangle\langle i|$, so$$|v_k\rangle=\Bbb I|v_k\rangle=\sum_i\langle i,\,v_k\rangle|i\rangle,\,\langle v_k|=|v_k\rangle^\dagger=\sum_i\langle v_k,\,i\rangle\langle i|.$$Since$$\langle u,\,v\rangle=\sum_{ij}\langle u,\,i\rangle\langle j,\,v\rangle\langle i,\,j\rangle=\sum_i\langle u,\,i\rangle\langle i,\,v\rangle$$recovers the usual sum-of-products formulation,$$\langle v_k,\,Kv_k\rangle=\sum_i\langle v_k,\,i\rangle\langle i,\,Kv_k\rangle=\sum_i\langle v_k,\,i\rangle\lambda_k\langle i,\,v_k\rangle=\lambda_k\langle v_k,\,v_k\rangle.$$

Comment: I was really curious about that,It helped me a lot to understand! Thank you!